# How to get current Date from Internet via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
function fun_voting_started(){
var now = new Date();
var now_date = now.getDate();
var now_month = now.getMonth(); now_month++;
var now_year = now.getFullYear();
var now_hours = now.getHours();
var now_min = now.getMinutes();
var now_sec = now.getSeconds();
var voting_started = now_year + "-" + now_month + "-" + now_date + " " + now_hours + ":" + now_min + ":" + now_sec; 
return voting_started;
}
```

This function loads Date from computer, but sometimes user have other Date than is current. How can I get the current Date from Internet?

Comment: you have to have a backend server.

Comment: And it depends on what time it is, where the user is, what server they are first connected to, and so on..

Comment: Make an AJAX call to: http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json

Comment: If the client chose to have a wrong date, what do you want to do against that? If you want to do this to avoid manipulations, you cannot. Always to check them serverside.

Comment: What do you understand under "current Date"? Time is something relative. The current date in the city the user is living, or the city you are living?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering this purely from a PoC perspective to the question title "*How to get current Date from Internet via JavaScript*", irrespective of how useful or useless it might be.

You can get the time from an Internet Time Server (or any server for that matter) which publishes an API for you to do that. You may search the web to find one.

For example, [(this)](http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json) and [(this)](http://www.timeapi.org/)

These services support JSONP for AJAX callback with Javascript.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/n66eP/***

*JS*:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://timeapi.org/utc/now.json',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.dateString);
    }
});
```

The service returns an object with date string. Just need to access the dateString property here.

Comment: thanks and how can I convert to this format? DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: @user3357400: well, that's another question for another day :) That has been asked and answered so many times on SO. Please search.

Comment: Those links are dead now.  Try using [get date/time](http://worldtimeapi.org) instead.